# hotmail calendar api in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, asp.net-web-api, outlook, calendar, oauth-2.0

I have a simple wordpress website and want to show de dates for events
in http://www.bootstrap-year-calendar.com/#Examples/Full example
I create the events in outlook so I only need a get for a certain year.

I found this https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/calendar-rest-operations
but If a follow the examples they rederict to a login screen before getting a token.

So, knows someone whether there is a good step by step tutorial to show calendar events in a website without a redirect to a microsoft login page.

If there is a wordpress plugin for this, it would even better.